# How to restrict access from internet to containers ports on remote linux server?

Tags: security, docker, iptables, ubuntu-18.04

I use docker-compose on ubuntu 18 on remote server.
How, with iptables, can i block access from the internet to the docker port and only allow access to it from the localhost of this server?

For instance, i want to block 4150 port for internet. Trying this:
`iptables -A DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 4150 -j DROP` does not block the port - still can access to it from the internet (not from server machine).

How can i block access from internet to all ports that are on the server, but allow only 22,80 ? And keep that ports available from localhost of the server (eg from the server itself) ?

Comment: Do you need an iptables solution, or do you just want to publish a port that can only be reached by localhost?

Comment: BMitch i need the iptables solution, but for now i am also interesting in second , that you mentioned=)

Answer (score 2):

Not the IPTables based solution you're looking for, but a much simpler solution is to only publish to a specific interface, instead of all interfaces. And when that interface is the loopback interface, e.g. 127.0.0.1, you'll only be able to access the port locally. To do this, add the interface to the beginning of the publish spec:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:4150:4150 ...
```

Or a similar syntax in the compose file:

```
...
  ports:
  - 127.0.0.1:4150:4150
...
```

---

As for why the command you tried using didn't work, this needs `conntrack` to get the original port rather than the docker mapped port:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp -m contrack --ctorigdstport 4150 -j DROP
```

This also changed from `-A` (append) to `-I` (insert) because there's a default rule to accept everything in that list.

Comment: can we access it through Nginx proxy_pass which is pointing at it?

Comment: @GithendraMcShane I don't think there's enough detail there to day, and that's not a request to clarify the answer here. Please post a new question instead.